# Is there any ways to get all the values of specific attribute from JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json

"item": [
{
"name": "default-user",
"item": [
{
"name": "set-up",
"item": [
{
"name": "/identity-service/token [Admin SSO Auth] [default-user]",
"event": [
{
"listen": "test",
"script": {
"id": "87ee6424-4b8f-444c-96d8-0c11e66e0820",
"exec": [
"var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + "  200 OK", function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("admin_access_token", jsonData.access_token);\r",
"\r",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");\r",
"    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");\r",
"}"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
},
{
"listen": "prerequest",
"script": {
"id": "527f6d95-6eac-46e0-b030-9e3045948344",
"exec": [
"pm.collectionVariables.set("bundlesUsername", "apipostmantestbundles@gmail.com");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
}
],
"request": {
"auth": {
"type": "noauth"
},
"method": "GET",
"header": [
{
"key": "Content-Type",
"name": "Content-Type",
"type": "text",
"value": "application/json"
}
],
"url": {
"raw": "{{ssourl}}/identity-service/token?grant_type=password&scope=openid+profile+email&client_id={{clientId}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&username={{bundlesUsername}}&password={{ssoAdminPassword}}",
"host": [
"{{ssourl}}"
],
"path": [
"identity-service",
"token"
],
"query": [
{
"key": "grant_type",
"value": "password"
},
{
"key": "scope",
"value": "openid+profile+email"
},
{
"key": "client_id",
"value": "{{clientId}}"
},
{
"key": "client_secret",
"value": "{{clientSecret}}"
},
{
"key": "username",
"value": "{{bundlesUsername}}"
},
{
"key": "password",
"value": "{{ssoAdminPassword}}"
}
]
},
"description": "Generating Authentication token for successfull login"
},
"response": []
},
{
"name": "/roles [Get Default Role RoleId] [default-user]",
"event": [
{
"listen": "test",
"script": {
"id": "86b3d7db-85f7-474e-9c0d-cd3081bf6480",
"exec": [
"var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Response status is 200 OK", function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Get the Default Role roleId", () => { \r",
"    var jsonResponse = jsonData.find(jsonData => jsonData.value == pm.environment.get("defaultRole"));\r",
"\tpm.collectionVariables.set("defaultRoleId", jsonResponse.id);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");\r",
"    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");\r",
"}"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
},
{
"listen": "prerequest",
"script": {
"id": "fd0d704f-1b71-4220-8244-e384d8a16a42",
"exec": [
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
}
],
"request": {
"method": "GET",
"header": [
{
"key": "Auth",
"value": "{{admin_access_token}}",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Content-Type",
"value": "application/json",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Accept-Language",
"value": "en",
"type": "text"
}
],
"url": {
"raw": "{{url}}/roles",
"host": [
"{{url}}"
],
"path": [
"roles"
]
},
"description": "Get the Default role Role Id"
},
"response": []
},
{
"name": "/users [Get UserId] [default-user]",
"event": [
{
"listen": "test",
"script": {
"id": "5ea818f4-7072-496d-8927-230ba331e5c7",
"exec": [
"var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Response status is 200 OK", function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Get the Default user userId", () => { \r",
"    var jsonResponse = jsonData.find(jsonData => jsonData.username == pm.environment.get("ssoDefaultUsername"));\r",
"\tpm.collectionVariables.set("userId", jsonResponse.id);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");\r",
"    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");\r",
"}"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
},
{
"listen": "prerequest",
"script": {
"id": "727132f3-8e9b-4f51-8e84-c88f872f5519",
"exec": [
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
}
],
"request": {
"method": "GET",
"header": [
{
"key": "Auth",
"value": "{{admin_access_token}}",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Content-Type",
"value": "application/json",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Accept-Language",
"value": "en",
"type": "text"
}
],
"url": {
"raw": "{{url}}/users",
"host": [
"{{url}}"
],
"path": [
"users"
]
},
"description": "Get the User Id for the user"
},
"response": []
},
{
"name": "/roles [Create Role] [default-user]",
"event": [
{
"listen": "prerequest",
"script": {
"id": "585bfe92-74f7-48b7-b1cb-c5ed1e06fb03",
"exec": [
"pm.collectionVariables.set("randomValue", *.random(1, 5000000));\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
},
{
"listen": "test",
"script": {
"id": "31e104ce-e7fd-4308-985c-e44a2df88ef4",
"exec": [
"var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Response status is 200", function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Creating the role", function () {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.set("roleId",jsonData.id);\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.set("value",jsonData.value);\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.set("description",jsonData.description);    \r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");\r",
"    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");\r",
"}"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
}
],
"request": {
"method": "POST",
"header": [
{
"key": "Auth",
"value": "{{admin_access_token}}",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Accept-Language",
"value": "en",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Content-Type",
"value": "application/json",
"type": "text"
}
],
"body": {
"mode": "raw",
"raw": "{\r\n    "roleName": "Postman_Test_Default_User_Role*{{randomValue}}",\r\n    "roleDescription": "Postman Test Default_User Role"\r\n}",
"options": {
"raw": {
"language": "json"
}
}
},
"url": {
"raw": "{{url}}/roles",
"host": [
"{{url}}"
],
"path": [
"roles"
]
},
"description": "Creating a new role to perform validation"
},
"response": []
},
{
"name": "/permissions [Get Permission Id's] [default-user]",
"event": [
{
"listen": "test",
"script": {
"id": "5ac41ac8-157e-41c3-abba-56c593b84229",
"exec": [
"var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Response status is 200", function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"var permissionIds = [];\r",
"var permissionNames = pm.environment.get("defaultUserPermissions");\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Get The Permission Ids based on Permission Names", () => {\r",
"    for (var count = 0; count < permissionNames.length; count++) {\r",
"        for (var index = 0; index < jsonData.length; index++) {\r",
"            if (permissionNames[count] == jsonData[index].value) {\r",
"                permissionIds.push(jsonData[index].id);\r",
"                break;\r",
"            }\r",
"        }\r",
"    }\r",
"    pm.expect(permissionIds.length == permissionNames.length).to.eql(true);\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.set("permissionId", permissionIds);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");\r",
"    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");\r",
"}"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
},
{
"listen": "prerequest",
"script": {
"id": "9c85d089-6860-472d-877b-3283ef2f0c03",
"exec": [
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
}
],
"request": {
"method": "GET",
"header": [
{
"key": "Auth",
"value": "{{admin_access_token}}",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Content-Type",
"value": "application/json",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Accept-Language",
"value": "en",
"type": "text"
}
],
"url": {
"raw": "{{url}}/permissions",
"host": [
"{{url}}"
],
"path": [
"permissions"
]
},
"description": "Get the Permission Id's based on the Permission names"
},
"response": []
},
{
"name": "/roles/{{roleId}}/permissions [Assign permissions to the role] [default-user]",
"event": [
{
"listen": "prerequest",
"script": {
"id": "543f1b03-31ae-4635-ab16-396e796c20a5",
"exec": [
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
},
{
"listen": "test",
"script": {
"id": "0d444323-ff9b-4c1b-9256-d012c0495df4",
"exec": [
"var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Response status is 200", function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Add the permissions to the role id ", () => {\r",
"    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql(pm.collectionVariables.get("roleId"));\r",
"    pm.expect(jsonData.value).to.eql(pm.collectionVariables.get("value"));\r",
"    pm.expect(jsonData.description).to.eql(pm.collectionVariables.get("description"));\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");\r",
"    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");\r",
"}"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
}
],
"request": {
"method": "PUT",
"header": [
{
"key": "Auth",
"value": "{{admin_access_token}}",
"type": "text"
}
],
"body": {
"mode": "raw",
"raw": "{\r\n    "permissionIds": [\r\n       {{permissionId}}\r\n    ]\r\n}",
"options": {
"raw": {
"language": "json"
}
}
},
"url": {
"raw": "{{url}}/roles/{{roleId}}/permissions",
"host": [
"{{url}}"
],
"path": [
"roles",
"{{roleId}}",
"permissions"
]
},
"description": "Assign the permissions to the role"
},
"response": []
},
{
"name": "/users/{{userId}}/roles  [Assign the role to the user] [default-user]",
"event": [
{
"listen": "prerequest",
"script": {
"id": "d47b0c84-4fbb-4bb3-b76c-3e410d39aaaa",
"exec": [
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
},
{
"listen": "test",
"script": {
"id": "7f2b63f0-d6bc-4818-927e-a9535130586f",
"exec": [
"var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Response status is 200 OK", function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + " Should have correct properties", function () {\r",
"    pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("id").eql(pm.collectionVariables.get("userId"));\r",
"    pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("username").to.eql(pm.environment.get("ssoDefaultUsername"));\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");\r",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");\r",
"    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");\r",
"}"
],
"type": "text/javascript"
}
}
],
"request": {
"method": "PUT",
"header": [
{
"key": "Auth",
"value": "{{admin_access_token}}",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Content-Type",
"value": "application/json",
"type": "text"
},
{
"key": "Accept-Language",
"value": "en",
"type": "text"
}
],
"body": {
"mode": "raw",
"raw": "{\r\n\t"roleIds":[{{roleId}}]\r\n}",
"options": {
"raw": {
"language": "json"
}
}
},
"url": {
"raw": "{{url}}/users/{{userId}}/roles",
"host": [
"{{url}}"
],
"path": [
"users",
"{{userId}}",
"roles"
]
},
"description": "Assign the role to the user"
},
"response": []
},],
"protocolProfileBehavior": {}
},
"protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
],
"protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}[image]From the below JSON I need to get the values ofattribute "exec"

Comment: Please do not post huge and/or unformatted JSON documents when asking questions. Post a small representative sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonpath, like this:
`$..exec`
[image]

Such as this library: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

#### Usage:

add pom

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

code:

```java
String json = "...";
JSONArray list = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$..exec");
System.out.println(list);
```

output:

```
[["var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);",
"",
"pm.test(\"Response status is 200 OK\",
 function () {",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);",
"});",
"",
"pm.collectionVariables.set(\"access_token\",
 jsonData.access_token);",
"",
"if (pm.collectionVariables.has(\"skipResponseTimeValidation\") || pm.collectionVariables.has(\"skipContentTypeValidation\")) {",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset(\"skipResponseTimeValidation\");",
"    pm.collectionVariables.unset(\"skipContentTypeValidation\");",
"    console.log(\"Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables\");",
"}"],

["pm.collectionVariables.set(\"systemsUsername\",
 \"apipostmantestsystems@gmail.com\");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set(\"systemsPassword\",
 \"post123!\");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set(\"skipResponseTimeValidation\");\r",
"pm.collectionVariables.set(\"skipContentTypeValidation\");"],

[""],

[""],

["var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
"\r",
"var sysName = [\"eCl@ss\"];\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + \" 200\",
 function () {\r",
"    pm.response.to.have.status(200);\r",
"});\r",
"\r",
"pm.test(request.name + \" Verify the systems and its attributes \",
 () => {   \r",
"    flag = false;\r",
"        for (var count = 0; count < jsonData.length; count++) {\r",
"             if (sysName == jsonData[count].details[0].name ) {\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[count]).to.have.property(\"code\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[count]).to.have.property(\"systemVersion\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails).to.have.property(\"id\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property(\"id\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property(\"value\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property(\"description\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property(\"priority\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].localizedDetails).to.have.property(\"name\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0]).to.have.property(\"id\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property(\"id\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property(\"value\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property(\"description\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property(\"priority\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0]).to.have.property(\"name\");\r",
"                  pm.expect(jsonData[0]).to.have.property(\"allowMultiple\");\r",
"                  pm.collectionVariables.set(\"systemId\",
 jsonData[count].id);\r",
"        flag = true;\r",
"        break; \r",
"            }\r",
"        }\r",
"        pm.expect(flag).to.eql(true);\r",
"});"],

[""]]
```

#### Each all line:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  JSONArray subList = (JSONArray) list.get(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < subList.size(); j++) {
    String execLine = (String) subList.get(j);
    System.out.println(execLine);
  }
}
```

output:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test("Response status is 200 OK", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.collectionVariables.set("access_token", jsonData.access_token);

if (pm.collectionVariables.has("skipResponseTimeValidation") || pm.collectionVariables.has("skipContentTypeValidation")) {
    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipResponseTimeValidation");
    pm.collectionVariables.unset("skipContentTypeValidation");
    console.log("Unset skipResponseTimeValidation and skipContentTypeValidation collection variables");
}
pm.collectionVariables.set("systemsUsername", "apipostmantestsystems@gmail.com");
pm.collectionVariables.set("systemsPassword", "post123!");
pm.collectionVariables.set("skipResponseTimeValidation");
pm.collectionVariables.set("skipContentTypeValidation");


var jsonData = pm.response.json();

var sysName = ["eCl@ss"];

pm.test(request.name + " 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test(request.name + " Verify the systems and its attributes ", () => {   
    flag = false;
        for (var count = 0; count < jsonData.length; count++) {
             if (sysName == jsonData[count].details[0].name ) {
                  pm.expect(jsonData[count]).to.have.property("code");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[count]).to.have.property("systemVersion");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails).to.have.property("id");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property("id");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property("value");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[count].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property("description");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].localizedDetails.language).to.have.property("priority");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].localizedDetails).to.have.property("name");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0]).to.have.property("id");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property("id");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property("value");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property("description");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0].language).to.have.property("priority");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0].details[0]).to.have.property("name");
                  pm.expect(jsonData[0]).to.have.property("allowMultiple");
                  pm.collectionVariables.set("systemId", jsonData[count].id);
        flag = true;
        break; 
            }
        }
        pm.expect(flag).to.eql(true);
});
```

Comment: Yes, Its working. I just need to validate the array one by one. I tried to print the values from list one by one. But its throwing "java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String".

Comment: @mathi Because this is a two-dimensional array, the outer layer is the array of exec, and the inner layer is the value of exec.

Comment: @mathi I added an example to the answer, Only need to use double loop.

Comment: Perfect!! I'm stuck in another step. Actually, we are getting all the values of 'exec' attribute from the JSON. All I need is, Need 'name' attribute value along with the 'exec'. Just attached the screenshot and  JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, what you are trying to achieve is to find and get all the occurrences of a given Key (in your case, key 'exec' occurs 6 times) in the whole JSON.

I think what you are looking for could be one of the methods in [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html):-

1. findValues()
2. findValuesAsText()
3. findParents(...)

These all are variations of finding values of fields with the given field name. Returns either a List of JsonNodes (1 and 2) and List of Strings (2).

Comment: Yes! You are correct. I just want all the values of  attribute "exec". Irrespective of parent or child nodes. Can you please provide some examples using above methods!

Comment: please check out their documentation https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html, you can easily find what each of these methods does.